# Song sung in Hebrew, English, and Russian with words "life is a narrow bridge."

Tags: translation, music, shabbat-songs

**Disclaimer:** This question is not about religion, per se; however, it does have to do with jewish culture.

My rabbi had us sing some song during a few shabbats.

However, I don't remember most of the lyrics. I do recall one phrase: "life is a narrow bridge."

We sang it first in Hebrew, then English and Russian (all three had the same tune).

**What is this song called, and where can I find the lyrics in all three languages (preferably with Romanization of Hebrew and Russian)?**

Comment: Probably the breslev song. Kol haolam kulo gesher tzar mi'od etc.

Comment: [Lyrics to "Kol Ha'olam Kulo"](https://jwa.org/media/lyrics-to-kol-haolam-kulo) Hebrew transliterated and translated to English.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's probably "Kol ha'olam kulo gesher tzar me'od, veha'ikar lo le'fached klal". It is composed by Rabbi Boruch Chait, and the lyrics are from Rav Nachman of Breslov. The English version is: "The whole world is a very narrow bridge, and the main thing to recall: have no fear at all".

Comment: Ah, yes. That's the song. Do you know of a source that has the whole lyrics in English (and Romanization of Hebrew and Russian)?

Comment: @SirJony well, as far as the English lyrics go, that IS the whole thing! I don't know offhand where to find Romanization, but there are probably many clips online of people singing it in all 3 languages, if that helps.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize it was so short!

Comment: @SirJony Yes, the whole song is very short, but the main thing is not to let that frighten you :)

Comment: Yes, I recall. :)

Answer (score 1):

I can't say for certain but agree with comment to your question. It sounds like the song based on a discourse from Likkutei Moharan Tinyanah, end of siman 48:2, called The Whole World (כל העולם כלו). Here is a https://youtu.be/x5tdi0zzvDM.

> ודע, שהאדם צריך לעבר על גשר צר מאד מאד, והכלל והעקר - שלא יתפחד כלל: ‏

I just found this rendition sung by a Chabad shaliach with all three versions as you remember it. Enjoy!

[The whole wide world is a very narrow bridge](https://youtu.be/jZP-IR1Mg0w)

And the alternate translation you requested is below in the comments.

Comment: I added the text from the book I hope this is OK

Comment: This chapter (48) is fantastic!